# How do I make PostgreSQL include all the months where I did not buy anything?

Tags: postgresql, query, statistics

I have this query:

```
SELECT avg(sum)
FROM
(
    SELECT date_trunc('month', "timestamp"), sum(amount) as sum
    FROM bookkeeping WHERE summary LIKE 'Bitcoin purchase:%'
    GROUP BY date_trunc('month', "timestamp")
) a
```

It gave me an impossible average cost of my Bitcoin purchases per month. I soon found out why: it ignores all the numerous months over the years where I did not buy Bitcoin at all, including only months when I did buy at least once. Since there aren't a ton of "empty" months included (with 0 for sum), it does the average of the sums for only the months where I bought at least once, so the average becomes completely wrong.

How do I make it "invent" rows for the months which aren't represented by at least one record, so that the avg(sum) will actually be meaningful?

Comment: This is a common problem. The basic solution is to generate a list of all the months you're interested in with 0 as sum and outer join that to your aggregation. There are good existing questions and answers here on this topic -- I'll find the best one and mark your question as a duplicate of that.

Comment: @Colin'tHart - I only saw your bits after posting my own answer - mine includes advice on using `EXTRACT` instead of `DATE_TRUNC` and also about using `COALESCE` - **way** too long for a comment. If you (or anybody) feels that it's just a dup, then I'll delete - but I think the bits  above and beyond the simple "answer" are helpful...

Answer (score 1):

You might like to try this (see the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=edc3ad1e16e06b22099292defb0a5255)):

```
CREATE TABLE cal (dc) AS 
SELECT GENERATE_SERIES
       (
           (DATE '2020-01-01'),
           (DATE '2020-12-31'),
           interval '1 MONTH'
       )::DATE;
SELECT * FROM cal;
```

Result:

```
        dc
2020-01-01
2020-02-01
2020-03-01
2020-04-01
2020-05-01
2020-06-01
2020-07-01
2020-08-01
2020-09-01
2020-10-01
2020-11-01
2020-12-01
12 rows
```

Having done this, we now look at our bitcoin purchases:

```
CREATE TABLE bp  -- bitcoin_purchases
(
  bp_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  bp_count SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  coin_price DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL CHECK (coin_price > 0),
  bp_total DOUBLE PRECISION GENERATED ALWAYS AS (bp_count * coin_price) STORED
);
```

Note the use of a `GENERATED` column here - it's not absolutely necessary but helps make subsequent SQL easier.

Populate it:

```
INSERT INTO bp VALUES
('2020-01-05 10:00:00', '10',  '500'),
('2020-01-25 10:00:00', '20', '1000'),
('2020-03-05 10:00:00', '10', '1500'),
('2020-03-05 10:00:00', '10', '2000'),
('2020-05-17 10:00:00', '10', '2500'),
('2020-05-19 10:00:00', '10', '3000'),
('2020-07-23 10:00:00', '10', '500.45'),
('2020-07-27 10:00:00', '10', '500.45'),
('2020-09-30 10:00:00', '10', '500.45');
```

Then, you might want to do something like this:

```
SELECT 
  c.dc, DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', c.dc), bp.*, DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', bp_date) 
FROM cal c
LEFT JOIN bp
  ON c.dc = DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', bp.bp_date);
```

Result:

```
dc  date_trunc  bp_date bp_count    coin_price  bp_total    date_trunc
2020-01-01  2020-01-01 00:00:00+00  2020-01-05 10:00:00 10  500 5000    2020-01-01 00:00:00
2020-01-01  2020-01-01 00:00:00+00  2020-01-25 10:00:00 20  1000    20000   2020-01-01 00:00:00
2020-02-01  2020-02-01 00:00:00+00                  
2020-03-01  2020-03-01 00:00:00+00  2020-03-05 10:00:00 10  1500    15000   2020-03-01 00:00:00
2020-03-01  2020-03-01 00:00:00+00  2020-03-05 10:00:00 10  2000    20000   2020-03-01 00:00:00
2020-04-01  2020-04-01 00:00:00+01                  
2020-05-01  2020-05-01 00:00:00+01  2020-05-17 10:00:00 10  2500    25000   2020-05-01 00:00:00
2020-05-01  2020-05-01 00:00:00+01  2020-05-19 10:00:00 10  3000    30000   2020-05-01 00:00:00
2020-06-01  2020-06-01 00:00:00+01                  
2020-07-01  2020-07-01 00:00:00+01  2020-07-23 10:00:00 10  500.45  5004.5  2020-07-01 00:00:00
2020-07-01  2020-07-01 00:00:00+01  2020-07-27 10:00:00 10  500.45  5004.5  2020-07-01 00:00:00
2020-08-01  2020-08-01 00:00:00+01                  
2020-09-01  2020-09-01 00:00:00+01  2020-09-30 10:00:00 10  500.45  5004.5  2020-09-01 00:00:00
2020-10-01  2020-10-01 00:00:00+01                  
2020-11-01  2020-11-01 00:00:00+00                  
2020-12-01  2020-12-01 00:00:00+00                  
16 rows
```

Now, the [`DATE_TRUNC`](http://date_trunc(field,%20source%20%5B,%20time_zone%20%5D)) function isn't the one you want here - you want [`EXTRACT(field FROM source)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) - you have those large TIMESTAMP fields - whereas you could use the easier INTEGER(<sup>*</sup>) from `EXTRACT` - easier on the CPU...

```
SELECT 
  EXTRACT('MONTH'FROM c.dc) AS "Month:",
  COALESCE(SUM(bp_total), 0) "Amount/mth",
  COALESCE(SUM(bp_count), 0) AS "No. of coins", 
  COALESCE(ROUND(SUM(bp_total::NUMERIC)/SUM(bp_count), 2), 0) AS "Avg price/mth"
FROM cal c
LEFT JOIN bp
  ON EXTRACT('MONTH' FROM c.dc) = EXTRACT('MONTH' FROM bp.bp_date)
GROUP BY EXTRACT('MONTH' FROM c.dc)
ORDER BY EXTRACT('MONTH' FROM c.dc);
```

(<sup>*</sup>) it's not actually an `INT` but for the purposes of this dicussion, it's easier to deal with than the results of `DATE_TRUNC`.

Result (better viewed on [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=edc3ad1e16e06b22099292defb0a5255)):

```
Month:  Amount/mth  No. of coins    Avg price/mth
1   25000   30  833.33
2   0   0   0
3   35000   20  1750.00
4   0   0   0
5   55000   20  2750.00
6   0   0   0
7   10009   20  500.45
8   0   0   0
9   5004.5  10  500.45
10  0   0   0
11  0   0   0
12  0   0   0
```

Note the user of the [`COALESCE`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-coalesce/) function which puts `0`s in place of `NULL`s - now you can use this in a sub-`SELECT` and not have to worry about 3-valued logic which can trip people up!

You can also make use of window functions as follows:

```
SELECT 
  bp.bp_date, bp.coin_price AS "price",
  SUM(bp_count) OVER (PARTITION BY EXTRACT('MONTH' FROM bp.bp_date)) AS "No./mth",
  SUM(bp_count) OVER () AS "No. coints"
FROM bp
ORDER BY bp.bp_date;
```

Result:

```
bp_date price   No./mth No. coints
2020-01-05 10:00:00 500 50  120
2020-01-25 10:00:00 1000    50  120
2020-01-28 10:00:00 1250    50  120
2020-03-05 10:00:00 1500    20  120
2020-03-05 10:00:00 2000    20  120
2020-05-17 10:00:00 2500    20  120
2020-05-19 10:00:00 3000    20  120
2020-07-23 10:00:00 500.45  20  120
2020-07-27 10:00:00 500.45  20  120
2020-09-30 10:00:00 500.45  10  120
10 rows
```

See fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f9ec844a00a1deaa9fdeb04687f547ab). Window functions are very powerful - see [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/tutorial-window.html) for an introduction and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) for more detail.

p.s. welcome to the forum!

Comment: In spite of somebody downvoting my question, I feel rude for not understanding your answer. It clearly has effort put into it. Yet I don't understand it. Are you saying that I have to create a table and populate it with records?! This cannot be right. All of this looks insanely complicated to do something as common and basic as what I'm asking for. I'm absolutely, utterly lost.

Comment: @user15080516 - the table and data are made up by me - the first part was an example of how to use aggregates and a `LEFT JOIN` from the calendar table  to the purchases so that you get a record for **every** month whether there was a purchase or not. The other example is about how you can use window functions to calculate sums/totals/counts - (aggregates) over `PARTITION`s - i.e. by month, week, year... whatever... - hope it was helpful... you can upvote it if you want to!

Comment: Hmm. I see. I'm often baffled by how complex SQL queries become for things which I consider "super common/basic", though. It seems to happen again and again. I tried to upvote your answer just now, but the site doesn't let me.

Comment: @user15080516 - yes, it takes time to master the subtleties of SQL - even stuff that appears relatively "simple" can require more thought and effort than might be "obvious". Understanding `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`s (and `RIGHT` ones) and also (very important) `NULL`s is critical to mastering SQL. Also, study window functions. You might have to wait some time before upvoting and/or marking as correct.